# Curious if Barcode photo taken can be used in Xamarin Emulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, zxing.net

I have created a barcode scanner; That works fine.  I am using Xamarin Forms and working with Android.  I had recently received some barcode samples in photo format, however the photo's are not being recognized when I print them out and scan them.

Next, I would like to try to import the photos and use those as my background, to then see if it would recognize the barcode.

I am using ZXing.Net.Mobile and .Forms extension.  Is there any file, or code I can implement to point to a filepath and then load that image as my background?

Thanks for any answers or suggestions.

Comment: almost every visual element in XF has a BackgroundImage property.  However, this won't have any impact on how ZX scans the image.

Answer (score 0):

If photos are not recognized than it must be something wrong with your code. I don't see a point to test this this way. In your application it wont work anyways. ZXing.Net.Mobile uses camera to intercept frames and decode them in real time to match qr code pattern.